# iOS App getting crashed while its launch from notification

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification

[image]

Process Flow

1. Click on one notification from the notification tray.
2. App opened, suddenly click on iPad home button.
3. Now app in the background state.
4. Again go to notification tray and click on next notification.
5. Then app getting crashed and in Xcode get an error message like this.
   [ please refer the image ]

Comment: Instead of screenshot, it will be better to put your relevant code.

Comment: Looking at the stack trace looks like the code at `ViewController.loadAction()` does something it shouldn't do

Comment: what is the issue in loadAction() function. ?

Comment: @demosten how to identify or debug this issue in xcode.because nothing is shown in console or debug out window.

Answer (score 0):

I google some iOS debug skill posts.

1. [xcode debug skill 1](https://medium.com/@jameskrauserlee/xcode-debug-skill-90a879a09506)
2. [xcode debug skill 2](http://www.programering.com/a/MzM0UTMwATk.html)

It crashes at `ViewController.loadAction`, back to that step and give more codes about why you crash. Or, above debug skills posts could help you find out what happened.

Comment: how to view the actual debug output (meaning full and readable )instead of this machine code.

Comment: At you image, the stack trace has lines with number. You can click on the number 1, or number 2. Or, you can insert breakpoint in the `loadAction` method, and run by `step by step` to find out the crash reason.